# How to get spray paint?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I play Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas for iOS. During one of the first couple of missions, I believe Sweet hands Carl a can of spray paint to tag the streets. But, for some reason, after I completed the mission, I died and I lost the spray paint can. I can't seem to find another spray paint anywhere. Where can I find another spray paint?

Comment: Is there one behind CJ's house?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Ganton, Los Santos - In the upstairs bedroom of the Johnson House
>     after completing the mission Tagging Up Turf.
> - Ganton, Los Santos - On
>     the Pawn Shop roof, behind the Johnson house.
> - Las Colinas, Los Santos - Behind a house in the center of the district.
> - Sobell Rail Yards, Las Venturas - Between two storage buildings.

http://gta.wikia.com/Spray_Can

IIRC, the first one in the list should be the easiest one to access. It is right next to the save point you would be using at this point in the game.

Answer (score 2):

From [wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/Spray_Can):

[image]

> - Ganton, Los Santos - In the upstairs bedroom of the [Johnson House](http://gta.wikia.com/Johnson_House) after completing the mission [Tagging Up Turf](http://gta.wikia.com/Tagging_Up_Turf).
> - Ganton, Los Santos - On the [Pawn Shop](http://gta.wikia.com/Pawn_Shop) roof, behind the Johnson house.
> - Las Colinas, Los Santos - Behind a house in the center of the district.
> - Sobell Rail Yards, Las Venturas - Between two storage buildings.